# Using EnvironmentObject to update existing list

Tags: list, swiftui, environmentobject

I have an existing list, but I want to be able to add new items to it. Right now, I am using `@EnvironmentObject`, but when I add an element to the array, the view is not updated? I've seen solutions on the internet where you use  `objectWillChange.send()`, but as a beginner in Swift, I don't know how to manipulate it to do what I want.

Class

```
class ChecklistObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var description: String
    @Published var complete: Bool
    let ID: Int
    
    init(_ desc: String, _ complete: Bool, ID: Int){
        description = desc
        self.complete = complete
        self.ID = ID
    }
}

class Event: ObservableObject {
    @Published var Name: String
    @Published var CalendarID: Int
    var timeStart: Date
    var timeEnd: Date
    @Published var checklist = [ChecklistObject]()
    @Published var checklistSize = 0
    
    init(_ eventName: String, _ calID: Int, _ timeStart: Date, _ timeEnd: Date) {
        Name = eventName
        CalendarID = calID
        self.timeStart = timeStart
        self.timeEnd = timeEnd
        logger.log("Successfully created new event")
    }
    
    func newChecklistItem(Content: String){
        objectWillChange.send()
        checklist.append(ChecklistObject(Content, false, ID: getChecklistSize()))
        //checklistSize = checklistSize + 1
    }
    
    func getChecklistSize() -> Int {
        return checklist.count
    }
}
```

List

```
VStack (alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Checklist")
        .font(.title)
        .bold()
    ForEach(event.checklist.indices) { idx in
        ChecklistDisplayRow()
            .environmentObject(event.checklist[idx])
    }
    Spacer()
        .frame(width: 360, height: 10)
    Button(action: {
        event.newChecklistItem(Content: "New item")
        event.checklistSize = event.checklistSize + 1
    }) {
        HStack{
            if #available(OSX 11.0, *) {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            } else {
                Path{ path in
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y:0))
                    path.move(to:CGPoint(x: 0, y: 10))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 10))
                }
            }
            Text("Add new item")
                .font(.caption)
        }
    }
    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `checklist` is published, so it is not needed to call `objectWillChange.send()`, because it is sent automatically. I assume the issue is somewhere in injection Event object. Would you show complete code of view have List and parent one where it is created?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the version of `ForEach` that you are using. This version:

`init(_ data: Range<Int>, content: @escaping (Int) -> Content)`

"only reads the initial value of the provided data and doesn’t need to identify views across updates." ([Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-6db7u))

To get dynamic updating, you need to use one of the other forms of `ForEach`.

```
    ForEach(event.checklist, id: \.ID) { item in
        ChecklistDisplayRow()
            .environmentObject(item)
    }
```

You could even change the `ID` property of your `ChecklistObject` to `id` and then add `Identifiable` conformance.

```
    ForEach(event.checklist) { item in
        ChecklistDisplayRow()
            .environmentObject(item)
    }
```

(And though it's hard to say since we don't see the rest of your code, but does the `item` really need to be passed in as an `EnvironmentObject` or could it be done in the initializer for `ChecklistDisplayRow`?)

Comment: I passed it as an `EnvironmentObject` because I want to be able to change the value in the child view, but have it stored in the parent view because I want all of the data to be shared throughout the app. Thanks for your help!